# Generic constraint not applying

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have many types of `IWorkingPattern` interface...

```
public interface IWorkingPattern
{
    TimeSpan Start { get; }

    TimeSpan End { get; }
}
```

I want to be able to convert these within a dictionary into a flat Enumerable of `Timeslot`...

```
public class Timeslot
{
    public Timeslot(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
    }
}
```

To achieve this I have written the following generic helper method...

```
public IEnumerable<Timeslot> ToTimeslots<T>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, IEnumerable<T>>> datePatterns)
        where T : IWorkingPattern
    {
        Collection<Timeslot> timeslots = new Collection<Timeslot>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, IEnumerable<T>> datePattern in datePatterns)
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> pattern in datePattern.Value)
                timeslots.Add(new Timeslot(datePattern.Key + pattern.Start, datePattern.Key + pattern.End));

        return timeslots;
    }
```

However, when trying to complete I get 2 errors for the `Start` and `End` properties each saying:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'XXX' and no extension method 'XXX' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can get this working by casting each `pattern` in the second foreach loop (like: `((IWorkingPattern)pattern).Start`. However I'm sure I should not have to do this because of the interface constraint.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have it has `where T : IWorkingPattern` why not just make it `IWorkingPattern` instead of `T` in the first place?

Comment: `pattern` is `IEnumerable<T>` but you're trying to pick `Start` and `End` from `T`. Compiler is telling you that `IEnumerable<T>` is not the same as `T`.

Comment: Also you are trying to implement the method on an `IEnumerable` not on a particular object inside of it. Or what @Brian said

Comment: How about `foreach (var pattern in ...`. Or `T pattern` if you prefer.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder without generics I can't pass in different types that are nested in dictionaries. I.E. `ToTimeslots(new Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<MDerivedIWorkingPattern>>())`

Comment: Start using `var` to avoid such confusions

Comment: @IvanStoev No, using vars I learn nothing. I learned something today by not using var

Comment: Well, the next time you'll not be so lucky and will learn runtime exception.

Comment: To whom ever down voted, care to explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (IEnumerable<T> pattern in datePattern.Value)
```

This code can't possibly be right as you already know `datePattern.Value` is an `IEnumerable<T>` from the previous `foreach`.

While I haven't tested it, I suspect that this should be

```
foreach (T pattern in datePattern.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the properties of `IWorkingPattern` on a `IEnumerable` of `T` where `T` is `IWorkingPattern`. If you want to access the properties of each `IWorkingPattern` in the collection, you will have to enumerate it correctly. For example:

```
foreach (var pattern in datePattern.Value)
```

Also why make a generic method when it is constrained to one interface?

Comment: As stated above, using generics allows me to pass derived types within dictionaries that I would otehrwise have to cast explicitly if I tightly couple my parameter to the `IWorkingPattern` interface. Generics allow me to pass any dictionary as long the `T` within `IEnumerable<T>` derives from my constraint. `ToTimeslots(new Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<MDerivedIWorkingPattern>>())` would not compile if I did not not use generics.

Comment: @AndyClark I saw the comment after I posted the answer, no worries